# Fragments not showing using navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a navigation drawer to show some fragments in my app.
Somehow I can not get them visible in the MainActivity using a fragment-container.
Maybe I am overlooking something, could somebody pls assist?

Thank you in advance.

MainActivity java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set the fragment initially

        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Set the fragment initially
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            // Set the fragment initially
            FactuurFragment fragment = new FactuurFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            transaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

App_bar_main.xml with the fragment container:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
> tools:context=".MainActivity">
>
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
>         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
> </FrameLayout>
>
> <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>     android:id="@+id/fab"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
>     android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
>     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
>
> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
> ```

Main Fragment.xml:

> ```
> <FrameLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> tools:context=".MainFragment">
>
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="MAIN"
>     android:padding="8dp"
>     android:textColor="#fff"
>     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>     android:textSize="28sp"
>     android:id="@+id/main_button"
>     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /> 
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

MainFragment java:

> ```
> import android.os.Bundle; 
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
> import android.view.View; 
> import android.view.ViewGroup; 
> import android.widget.Button;
>
> public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
>
>
> public MainFragment() {
>     // Required empty public constructor
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
>
>     final Button mainButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_button);
>     mainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>
>                  mainButton.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
>         }
>     });
>     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
>     return rootView;
> }
>
> }
> ```

**EDIT:**
Activity_Main.xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
> tools:openDrawer="start">
>
> <include
>     layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>
> <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_gravity="start"
>     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>     app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
>     app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
>
> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
> ```

Comment: Check here http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: We are missing your main activity layout xml. Could you please post activity_main.xml ? Fragment container needs to be in it.

Comment: @arsent I posted the activity main, thx again for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything's ok except your fragment content stays behind the toolbar and you don't see it. Add a margin with the size of the action bar on top and you'll see the button.

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

So, it'll be like this.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Also, I'd separate Action bar view from the main fragment container. Move the main fragment container to main activity layout.

Comment: Aaaa, 1 line of code. How could I overlooked?
Many thx arsent, works now.